# ¿Cómo puedo guardar el usuario que está logueado?

Tags: html, angularjs, jhipster

Estoy haciendo una aplicación generada con JHipster, en los formularios que envian los usuarios necesito guardar quién lo envió. Estoy usuando AngularJS para manejar el front.

Este es el HTML:
`

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
            aria-hidden="true" ng-click="vm.clear()">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myPlanoLabel"
        data-translate="obrasPrivadas4App.plano.home.createOrEditLabel">Create
        or edit a Plano</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <jhi-alert-error></jhi-alert-error>
    <div class="form-group" ng-show="vm.plano.id">
        <label for="id" data-translate="global.field.id">ID</label> <input
            type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id"
            ng-model="vm.plano.id" readonly />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 no-padding-left">
        <label class="control-label"
               data-translate="obrasPrivadas4App.plano.fecha" for="field_fecha">Fecha</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="field_fecha" type="text" class="form-control"
                   name="fecha" datetime-picker="{{dateformat}}"
                   ng-model="vm.plano.fecha" readonly/>
            <span class="input-group-btn">

            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 no-padding-left">
        <label class="control-label"
               data-translate="obrasPrivadas4App.plano.responsable"
               for="field_responsable">Responsable</label> <input type="text"
               class="form-control" name="responsable" id="field_responsable"
               ng-model="vm.plano.responsable" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 no-padding-left">
        <label class="control-label"
               data-translate="obrasPrivadas4App.plano.cuitResponsable"
               for="field_cuitResponsable">CUIL Responsable</label> <input
               type="number" class="form-control" name="cuitResponsable"
               placeholder="Ingrese solo números" max="99999999999"
               id="field_cuitResponsable" ng-model="vm.plano.cuitResponsable" required/>
    </div>
</div>


                    <!--           PROFESIONAL        
           <div class="col-xs-3 no-padding-left">
               <label data-translate="obrasPrivadas4App.plano.profesional" for="field_profesional">Profesional</label>
               <select class="form-control" id="field_profesional" name="profesional" ng-model="vm.plano.profesional" ng-options="profesional as profesional.usuario.login for profesional in vm.profesionals track by profesional.profesional.login">
                   <option value=""></option>
               </select>
           </div>
                   -->


    <div class="row"/>


    <div class="modal-body">
        <h4>Detalle del Plano</h4>
        <button type="button" ng-click="vm.togglePlanoDetalle()"
                class="btn btn-primary">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;<span>Agregar
                Detalle de Plano</span>
        </button>
        <hr>

        <div uib-collapse="vm.isPlanoDetalleCollapsed">
            <div class="col-md-12 center-block">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label data-translate="Tipo de Plano" for="field_tipoPlano">Tipo Plano</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="field_tipoPlano" name="tipoPlano" ng-model="vm.planoDetalle.tipoPlano" ng-options="tipoPlano as tipoPlano.descripcion for tipoPlano in vm.tipoplanos| orderBy:'id' track by tipoPlano.descripcion">
                        <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
                </div>    


                <div class="col-xs-3 no-padding-left" ngf-drop
                     ngf-change="vm.setArchivo($file, vm.planoDetalle.archivo)">
                    <label class="control-label" data-translate="Archivo"
                           for="field_archivo">Archivo</label>
                    <div>
                        <div ng-if="vm.planoDetalle.archivo.archivo" class="help-block clearfix">
                            <a class="pull-left"
                               ng-click="vm.openFile(vm.planoDetalle.archivo.archivoContentType, vm.planoDetalle.archivo.archivo)"
                               data-translate="entity.action.open">open</a>
                            <button type="button"
                                    ng-click="vm.planoDetalle.archivo.archivo = null;vm.planoDetalle.archivo.archivoContentType = null;"
                                    class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" ngf-select
                                class="btn btn-default btn-block"
                                ngf-change="vm.setArchivo($file, vm.planoDetalle.archivo)"
                                data-translate="Adjuntar archivo .PDF">Add blob
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="archivo"
                           id="field_archivo" ng-model="vm.planoDetalle.archivo.archivo"/> 
                    <input
                           type="hidden" class="form-control" name="archivoContentType"
                           id="field_archivoContentType"
                           ng-model="vm.planoDetalle.archivo.archivoContentType" />
                </div>

                <div class="row"/>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" data-translate="Comentario"
                           for="field_observaciones">Observaciones</label> <input
                           type="text" class="form-control" name="observaciones"
                           id="field_observaciones" ng-model="vm.planoDetalle.observaciones" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 center-block">
                    <button type="button"
                            ng-click="vm.addPlanoDetalle(vm.planoDetalle)"
                            ng-disabled="editForm.observaciones.$invalid || editForm.archivo.$invalid"
                            class="btn btn-primary">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>&nbsp;<span>Guardar
                            Detalle de Plano</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" ng-click="vm.togglePlanoDetalle()"
                            class="btn btn-danger">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>&nbsp;<span>Salir</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- Fin uib-collapse -->


        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="jh-table table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><span
                                data-translate="obrasPrivadas4App.plano.tipoPlano">C�digo</span>
                        </th>
                        <th><span
                                data-translate="Comentario">Descripcion</span>
                        </th>
                        <th><span
                                data-translate="obrasPrivadas4App.plano.archivo">Descripcion</span>
                        </th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="planoDetalle in vm.plano.planoDetalles">
                        <td>{{planoDetalle.tipoPlano.descripcion}}</td>
                        <td>{{planoDetalle.observaciones}}</td>
                        <td><a class="pull-left"
                               ng-click="vm.openFile(vm.planoDetalle.archivo.archivoContentType, vm.planoDetalle.archivo.archivo)"
                               data-translate="Click para ver archivo">open</a></td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <div class="btn-group flex-btn-group-container">
                                <button type="button"
                                        ng-click="vm.removePlanoDetalle($index)"
                                        class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
        <!-- fin class table-responsive -->

    </div>
    <!-- Fin form class -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"
            ng-click="vm.clear()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span>&nbsp;<span
            data-translate="entity.action.cancel">Cancel</span>
    </button>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="editForm.$invalid || vm.isSaving"
            class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>&nbsp;<span
            data-translate="entity.action.save">Save</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

`
Y esta la parte de JS

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('obrasPrivadas4App').controller('PlanoDialogController',
            PlanoDialogController);

    PlanoDialogController.$inject = [ '$timeout', '$scope', '$stateParams',
            '$uibModalInstance', 'entity', 'Plano', 'PlanoDetalle',
            'Profesional', 'DataUtils', 'Archivo', 'Tramite', 'entityDetalle', 'entityTramite', 'entityArchivo', 'TipoPlano', '$q', 'Operador'];

    function PlanoDialogController($timeout, $scope, $stateParams,
            $uibModalInstance, entity, Plano, PlanoDetalle, Profesional,
            DataUtils, Archivo, Tramite, entityDetalle, entityTramite, entityArchivo, TipoPlano, $q, Operador) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.plano = entity;
        inicializarDetalle();

        vm.clear = clear;
        vm.datePickerOpenStatus = {};
        vm.openCalendar = openCalendar;
        vm.save = save;
        vm.planodetalles = PlanoDetalle.query();
        vm.profesionals = Profesional.query();
        vm.byteSize = DataUtils.byteSize;
        vm.openFile = DataUtils.openFile;
        vm.tramites = Tramite.query();
        vm.isPlanoDetalleCollapsed = true;
                vm.plano.fecha = new Date ();


        $timeout(function() {
            angular.element('.form-group:eq(1)>input').focus();
        });

        function clear() {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        }

        function save() {
            vm.isSaving = true;
            if (vm.plano.id !== null) {
                Plano.update(vm.plano, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
            } else {
                Plano.save(vm.plano, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
            }
        }

        function onSaveSuccess(result) {
            $scope.$emit('obrasPrivadas4App:planoUpdate', result);
            $uibModalInstance.close(result);
            vm.isSaving = false;
        }

        function onSaveError() {
            vm.isSaving = false;
        }

        vm.datePickerOpenStatus.fecha = false;

        function openCalendar(date) {
            vm.datePickerOpenStatus[date] = true;
        }
        function loadUser() {
            principal.identity().then(function(account) {
                vm.account = account;
                loadAll();
            });
        }
        vm.setArchivo = function($file, archivo) {
            if ($file) {
                DataUtils.toBase64($file, function(base64Data) {
                    $scope.$apply(function() {
                        archivo.archivo = base64Data;
                        archivo.archivoContentType = $file.type;
                    });
                });
            }
        };

                ////////////////////////////////////////
                //////////MUESTRA TIPO PLANO////////////
                ////////////////////////////////////////

                vm.tipoplanos = TipoPlano.query({filter: 'oficina-is-null'});
                    $q.all([vm.plano.$promise, vm.tipoplanos.$promise]).then(function() {
                        if (!vm.plano.tipoPlano || !vm.plano.tipoPlano.id) {
                    return $q.reject();
                        }
                    return TipoPlano.get({id : vm.plano.tipoPlano.id}).$promise;
                     }).then(function(tipoPlano) {
                vm.tipoplanos.push(tipoPlano);
                });



        // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // /// Funciones de Planos
        // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //// inicializamos el objeto detalle
        function inicializarDetalle() {
            vm.planoDetalle = entityDetalle;
            vm.planoDetalle.tramite = entityTramite;
            vm.planoDetalle.tramite.archivo = entityArchivo;
                        vm.plano.tipoPlano = entityDetalle;
        }


                function clearPlanoDetalle(){
                        vm.planoDetalle = null;
            vm.planoDetalle.tramite = null;
            vm.planoDetalle.tramite.archivo = null;
                        vm.plano.tipoPlano = null;
                }


        // Hace visible la carga
        vm.togglePlanoDetalle = function() {
            vm.isPlanoDetalleCollapsed = !vm.isPlanoDetalleCollapsed;
            inicializarDetalle();
            $scope.editForm.$setPristine();

        };

        vm.addPlanoDetalle = function(planoDetalle) {
            if (typeof vm.plano.planoDetalles === 'undefined') {
                vm.plano.planoDetalles = [];
            }
            vm.plano.planoDetalles.push(angular.copy(planoDetalle));
            vm.isPlanoDetalleCollapsed = true;
            inicializarDetalle();
            $scope.editForm.$setPristine();
                        clearPlanoDetalle();
        };

        vm.removePlanoDetalle = function(index) {
            vm.plano.planoDetalles.splice(index, 1);
        };


    }
    ;
})();
```

Gracias desde ya!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siendo el caso de AngularJS, JHipster tiene dentro del front-end un servicio llamado `Principal` en el archivo `principal.service.js` el cual tiene un método llamado `identity()` que regresa los datos del usuario.

Puedes ver un ejemplo de cómo utilizarlo desde el archivo `user-management.controller.js` y en su respectiva vista.

```
Principal.identity().then(function(account) {
    vm.currentAccount = account;
});
```

Por otra parte si deseas obtener el nombre de usuario desde el back-end puedes utilizar la clase `SecurityUtils.java` su método `getCurrentUserLogin()`.

Desconozco la versión de JHipster que este utilizando pero si es algo antigua el método regresara un tipo `String` en las más nuevas regresa `Optional<String>`.

Puedes ver un ejemplo de como utilizarla dentro de la clase `AccountResource.java`.

**UPDATE**

Una de las múltiples formas de setear el nombre de usuario a un objeto que tienes es la siguiente:

```
...
final String login = SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().orElse(Constants.SYSTEM_ACCOUNT)
Tramite tramite= ...;
tramite.setUsername(username);
...
```

Suponiendo que la clase `Tramite` tiene la propiedad *username* de tipo `String` asignará el login del usuario actual si lo encuentra o en caso contrario asignará el login de la cuenta del sistema.

Comment: Muchas gracias, desconozco la version de JHipster, el lunes cuando llegue al trabajo probaré con esto.
Y tenés razón, es AngulaJS.

Comment: Disculpa que responda despues de tanto tiempo, habia abandonado un poco el proyecto. La función efectivamente devuelve un Optional<String>, pero necesito setearsela a un Objeto, el cual contiene el usuario en cuestión. Alguna forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

```
//buscamos el usuario
SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
String user= (String) ((UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
```

Comment: Hola, las respuestas que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad porque les hace falta contexto y una descripción de lo que hacen o como solucionan el problema. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para añadir más detalle. Lee [answer] para más información.